# Random number generator

Tags: randomness, random

I am trying to hack a random number generator contract as follows :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Guess {

    uint256 private randNonce;
    uint256 private result;

    function randMod() internal returns(uint ){
        // increase nonce
        randNonce++;
        result = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, randNonce))) % 10;
        return result;
    }

    function guess(uint8 _guess) public returns(string memory) {
        randMod();
        if(_guess == result) {
            // (bool sent,)=msg.sender.call{value: 1 ether}("");
            // require(sent, "Failed to send ether");
            return "Hooray, you won";
        }else {
            return "OOPS, You lost";
        }
    }
    

}

contract Attack {
    event Answer(string Result);
    function attack(Guess guessAddress) public {
        uint randNonce = guessAddress.randNonce(); // Error
        uint answer = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, randNonce+1))) % 10;
        string memory resultz = guessAddress.guess(uint8(answer));
        emit Answer(resultz);
        
    }
}
```

I'm unable because randNonce is a private state variable.
So, is my contract safe?
Is there any other way to attack ?

Comment: Consider using an oracle for random number generation safely. You can check out [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/)

Comment: Yes, that too is an option that I evaluated, but its proving to be too costly.

Comment: You can not create true random numbers on-chain, it is not safe. You should be using an oracle.

Comment: Can you hack it ?

Comment: @Ashishkumar There's nothing private in Ethereum, someone off-chain can track the last used nonce and feed the attacker. Also you don't need to know the nonce, you could call guess repeatedly reverting when you don't guess, then nonce will not change, and you can call again with a new guess.